# Function not recognizing variable

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that simulates the spread of a virus within a matrix of people.

I'm getting an error where it says that 'cap' isn't recognized in the scope of the check_up function. Here is the function below along with the functions that call it.

```
void check_up(){
    for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<500;j++){
            if(hospital_stat[i][j]==1 && hospital[i][j].state!="Masked" && hospital[i][j].inICU == false){
                int orth=0;

                if(i-1>=0 && j-1>=0 && hospital_stat[i-1][j-1]==1 && hospital[i-1][j-1].state=="Sick" && !hospital[i-1][j-1].inICU)
                    orth++;

                if(i+1<500 && j+1<500 && hospital_stat[i+1][j+1]==1 && hospital[i+1][j+1].state=="Sick" && !hospital[i+1][j+1].inICU)
                    orth++;

                if(i-1>=0 && j+1<500 && hospital_stat[i-1][j+1]==1 && hospital[i-1][j+1].state=="Sick" && !hospital[i-1][j+1].inICU)
                    orth++;

                if(i+1<500 && j-1>=0 && hospital_stat[i+1][j-1]==1 && hospital[i+1][j-1].state=="Sick" && !hospital[i+1][j-1].inICU)
                    orth++;

                if(i+1<0 && hospital_stat[i+1][j]==1 && hospital[i+1][j].state=="Sick" && !hospital[i+1][j].inICU)
                    orth++;

                if(i-1>=0 && hospital_stat[i-1][j]==1 && hospital[i-1][j].state=="Sick" && !hospital[i-1][j].inICU)
                    orth++;

                if(j-1>=0 && hospital_stat[i][j-1]==1 && hospital[i][j-1].state=="Sick" && !hospital[i][j-1].inICU)
                    orth++;

                if( j+1<500 && hospital_stat[i][j+1]==1 && hospital[i][j+1].state=="Sick" && !hospital[i][j+1].inICU)
                    orth++;

                if(hospital[i][j].recovery>28 && cap>0){
                    hospital[i][j].inICU = true;
                    cap--;
                }
                if(hospital[i][j].state=="Sick"){
                    hospital[i][j].recovery--;
                    if(hospital[i][j].recovery==0)
                        hospital[i][j].state="Healthy";
                }
                if(orth>1 && hospital[i][j].state!="Healthy"){
                    hospital[i][j].state="Sick";
                    hospital[i][j].recovery += (14+(orth*7));
                }
                if(orth>2)
                    hospital[i][j].death--;
                }
            }
        }
}
void simulate(int rows, int cols, int cap, int out_time){
    for(int t=0;t<=out_time;t++){
        check_up();
        new_case(t);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int rows, cols, cap, out_time, n, t, prow, pcol;

    string name, state;

    init_matrix();

    cin>>rows>>cols>>cap>>out_time>>n;

    while(n--){
        cin >> t>>prow>>pcol>>name>>state;
        patient p(name, state, prow, pcol);
        tarr[t].push_back(p);
    }
    simulate(rows,cols,cap,out_time);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure where it's going wrong. I feel like it's something simple but I'm not sure what. Does anyone know what the error is?

Comment: In `void simulate(int rows, int cols, int cap, int out_time)`, only `out_time` is used, strange.

Comment: Typo: `i+1<0` -> `i+1<500`

Answer (score 0):

So `cap` isn't declared in `check_up` and that's what the compiler is correctly telling you.

`cap` is declared in `main` and in `simulate` (as a parameter) but not in `check_up`.

Assuming the `cap` in `simulate` is the same thing as the `cap` you are trying to use in `check_up` then you need to pass `cap` as a parameter to `check_up` exactly the same way that you passed it to `simulate`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the function `void check_up()` for instance  to `void check_up(int cap)`. `cap` is just known in the first called function `void simulate(...)`.

Also take care for out of bounds errors when accessing your arrays.